# Improve slow query count mongodb

Tags: mongodb, performance, count

I'm trying to improve the performance of a count query (to calculate pagination to display on a screen) on a collection of 1138633 documents. The query analyze 391232 document for 364497 returned but it takes ~2sc to be executed and i think it's too long.

My query looks like this:

```
db.myCollection.count({
            "$or" : [ 
                {
                    "field_1" : {
                        "$lte" : 1.0
                    }
                }, 
                {"field_1" : {
                        "$eq" : null
                    }
                }
            ],
            "field_2" : {
                "$eq" : false
            },
            "field_3" : {
                "$ne" : true
            },
            "field_4" : {
                "$eq" : "fr-FR"
            },
            "field_5" : {
                "$ne" : null
            },
            "field_6" : {
                "$ne" : null
            },
            "field_7" : {
                "$gte" : ISODate("2016-10-14T00:00:00.000Z")
            }
        })
```

**field_1** is a number , **field_2** and **field_3** a boolean, **field_5** a string and **field_6** an object ID which refer to a collection of 2 documents.

Here are my indexes (db.myCollection.getIndexes() ) :

```
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "db.myCollection"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "field_6" : 1,
            "field_7" : -1
        },
        "name" : "field_6_1_field_7_-1",
        "ns" : "db.myCollection",
        "background" : true
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "field_7" : 1
        },
        "name" : "field_7_1",
        "background" : true,
        "ns" : "db.myCollection"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "field_6" : 1
        },
        "name" : "field_6_1",
        "ns" : "db.myCollection",
        "background" : true
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "field_1" : 1.0
        },
        "name" : "field_1_1",
        "ns" : "db.myCollection"
    }
]
```

I tried everything , like force indexe using hint , change the order of the query ( and the order of the multi key index) but nothing work.

Someone have an idea on what can I try to improve the execution time of this query? Do you need more details? like informations of the executionStats?

Thanks.

EDIT : More Detail, i calculated how much document are concerned by the clause and here is my result : 
field 6 : 391232
field 1 lte 1  :721005
field 1 eq null : 417625
field 5 : 819688
field 4: 1123301
field 2 : 1138620
field 7: 1138630 (all document)
field 3: 1138630 (all document)

i reordered my query in the above order and i get ~1.82sc (0.2sc winned xD)

I assume the problem is because of the indexes which are maybe wrong.

For the detail index in explain do you know what section i have to check? here is what i found in execution plan about my indexes :

```
    "inputStage" : {
        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
        "nReturned" : 391232,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 427,
        "works" : 391234,
        "advanced" : 391232,
        "needTime" : 1,
        "needYield" : 0,
        "saveState" : 3060,
        "restoreState" : 3060,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "keyPattern" : {
            "field_6" : 1,
            "field_7" : -1
        },
        "indexName" : "field_6_1_field_7_-1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "multiKeyPaths" : {
            "field_6" : [],
            "field_7" : []
        },
        "isUnique" : false,
        "isSparse" : false,
        "isPartial" : false,
        "indexVersion" : 2,
        "direction" : "forward",
        "indexBounds" : {
            "field_6" : [ 
                "[MinKey, null)", 
                "(null, MaxKey]"
            ],
            "field_7" : [ 
                "[new Date(9223372036854775807), new Date(1491350400000)]"
            ]
        },
        "keysExamined" : 391233,
        "seeks" : 2,
        "dupsTested" : 0,
        "dupsDropped" : 0,
        "seenInvalidated" : 0
    }
```

Comment: EDIT : By default the query is using the index on field_6 (which is the Object ID) but when force use of all the other indexes ( i tried them all ) i'm getting even more execution time like ~4sc.

Comment: "change the order of the query" one general rule of thumb is to keep the order of the query i.e if field_2: true occurs in 20% of total docs and  "field_5": null occurs in 40% of docs, field_2 must be written ahead of field_5. You can briefly categorize your query and then decide the order of fields in your query.

Comment: can you please check the indexes with explain()  ? and give us some details

Comment: YasBES , do you know what section of explain i have to check ? Thanks

Comment: @ mehta-rohan = > I re ordered the query ( see EDIT detail ) and created an index with the 7 fields in the same order . By default the count is now using this new index but i'm still getting ~1.8sc execution time . I was wondering if this is normal or not? i dont have any reference of execution time query